# Blocks not shown in /user/logout page

Tags: blocks

Users must be logged in to see anything on my site; so it's important the user login block is always shown to anonymous users.

When users log out, they are normally redirected to the front page. A user has reported an issue where this doesn't happen; the user is kept at /user/logout, where the blocks are not shown.

If I manually navigate to that address, the redirection to the front page doesn't always happen to me, and I can also see that no blocks are shown.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to show the blocks also on the /user/logout page, or to be sure the redirection always happens?

Comment: If there was a way of making the blocks always show that seems like a more robust solution.

Comment: When the redirection to the front page doesn't happen, do you see an "Access denied" message, or do you see something else?

Comment: I see the "Access denied" message.

Comment: That is what I suspected: It's the only case where the redirection doesn't happen. I will write an answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there aren't modules that avoid the redirection happens, the only case the redirection from user/logout to the front page doesn't happen is when the user is already logged out. user/logout is defined as the following, in [user_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_menu/7).

```
  $items['user/logout'] = array(
    'title' => 'Log out', 
    'access callback' => 'user_is_logged_in', 
    'page callback' => 'user_logout', 
    'weight' => 10, 
    'menu_name' => 'user-menu', 
    'file' => 'user.pages.inc',
  );
```

When a menu is accessed from the users, Drupal first calls the access callback; if the access callback returns `TRUE`, then Drupal calls the page callback. In this case, the redirection is done from the page callback, which is never called when the user is logged out. (In that case, [user_is_logged_in()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_is_logged_in/7) returns `FALSE`.)

For a page like user/logout, the login block is not shown. In fact, [user_block_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_block_view/7) contains the following code, used to render the login block.

```
  // For usability's sake, avoid showing two login forms on one page.
  if (!$user->uid && !(arg(0) == 'user' && !is_numeric(arg(1)))) {
    $block['subject'] = t('User login');
    $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('user_login_block');
  }
  return $block;
```

What you can do is implementing [hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter/7) to show the login block also on user/logout, in the case the redirection to the front page doesn't happen for any reason.

```
function mymodule_block_view_user_login_alter(&$data, $block) {
  if (!$GLOBALS['user']->uid && $_GET['q'] == 'user/logout') {
    $data['subject'] = t('User login');
    $data['content'] = drupal_get_form('user_login_block');
  }
}
```